# syntax for java list interface used by hibernate in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, methods, collections

Sorry if this is a duplicate question and if you happen to have the answer or the other post, please let me know and I will delete this. However, I have tried to find documentation and answer to this, so if someone can explain the code for me, I will highly appreciate. I dont know if this is the correct structure of the question.

I have a class named: persondao.java with the following code:

```
public interface PersonaDao {

**public List<Person> showPerson();**
public void insertPerson (Person person);


}
```

Second, I have the class that implements this interface as follows:

```
public class PersonaDaoImplement implements PersonaDao {

@Override
public List<Person> showPersonas() {
    Session session = null;
    List<Person> lista = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Person");
        lista = (List<Person>) query.list();

    }
    catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return lista;

}//end
```

---

So what is the proper way or syntax when declaring a method inside the interface class?

as you can see its got  public List showPerson(); so its: [access modifier] LIST  and then ?????

Im asking this because using the list, I have seen many examples using the "proper way" the following line:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

but in the persondao.java class has the following line:

```
public List<Person> showPerson();
```

what 1st question>>>>> what is the correct way, syntax and a good example please?

Im totally confused cause the method next to  is not there in the other declaration, so is this another type of utility of what?

of after **`List<Person> [here it goes any method I want]`** ...........> is this valid? or is only used on interfaces? is there a special type for declaring a list in a interface?

Im confused how to use this type of list, can someone explain to me please?

Regards,

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but if you are overriding a method, it needs to have the same name in both places, you can't have `showPersonas()` overriding `showPerson()`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 1):

(i am assumming your issue is related to method overloading)

when java sees a method call it "tracks down" the correct method by the method name and the arguments (the number of arguments and their types).

your interface declares the following method:

```
public List<Person> showPerson()
```

its called `showPerson` and has no args.

your class states it overrides a method called `showpersonas`:

```
@Override
public List<Person> showPersonas() {...}
```

which is an unknown method.

see more info about overloading methods [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: I see what you mean! that was a typo, sorry, in fact the showPerson method is in the implementation class.I guess my confusion is how to declare a method to get all the items in the table with a list and I did not know that we can declare a method right after declaring the list of objects, basically, I will find more type of declarations with the list collection in java but I will check the link you gave me XD

Answer (score 0):

You code can't compile as radai suggested. All methods declared in an interface must be implemented in the non-abstract implementation (or at least in an abstract parent class).

As for your question the most common naming patterns for Data Access Code are:

```
public List<Person> getAll();
```

and

```
public List<Person> findAll();
```

I like S[pring Data way of naming methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods), not to mention that you get the full implementation automatically generated by following their query method naming standard.

Comment: I see, I guess my confusion is how to declare a method to get all the items in the table with a list and I did not know that we can declare a method right after declaring the list of objects. I will have to read more about list and methods using list to get data from a data base I guess

Comment: To use JPA or Hibernate you have to understand Java basics first.